# Why is this attempt to retrieve the minimum number of an array not working?

Tags: javascript

Max should be = 9.99, and min should be = 6.88

```js
let arr = [["2019","00","01", 9.99], ["2018","00","01", 9.32], ["2017","00","01", 6.88]]


let max = Math.max(Number(...arr.map((o) => { return o[3] }))); //9.99
let min = Math.min(Number(...arr.map((o) => { return o[3] }))); //9.99

console.log(min); 
console.log(max);
```

Comment: Remove the call to `Number(...)`

Comment: No need to use Number(array). Looks like it is using the first element to make it a number.

Comment: `Math.min(Number(9,99, 9.32, 6.88))`

Comment: What if you use Number(o[3]) ?

Comment: @TusharShahi `o[3]` is already a number

Comment: They mentioned a typescript error/warning and I was providing the option to cast to mitigate the error/warning. I know that o[3] is a number but as far as I know TS will not know it. Right?

Comment: @TusharShahi you are right, i just solved it then deleted the comment

Comment: @mouchin777 yet `Number(...xs)` is not a correct conversion. It only returns one single value, as all other function calls. It will not convert each of the values and return it. The correct conversion is `...xs.map(Number)` - map to number and spread the result. However, TS is a tad too strict in this case - `o[3]` returns a number. It's just that the `.map()` is typed to be generic for the array. [If you supply more information about your types it lets the compiler know what you're doing is safe](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8lPw)

Comment: @TusharShahi okay, I think they deleted that comment. If they declare the array with proper type, it should not throw an error. `let arr: Array<[string,string,string,number]>`

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [["2019","00","01", 9.99], ["2018","00","01", 9.32], ["2017","00","01", 6.88]];

let max = Math.max(...arr.map((o) => { return o[3] })); //9.99
let min = Math.min(...arr.map((o) => { return o[3] })); //6.88


console.log({
  max , min
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

Earlier, you had put Number around the mapped array. This converts the array to a number. However, you only wanted the individual elements to be numbers so move it inside the map function.

```js
let arr = [
  ["2019","00","01", 9.99],
  ["2018","00","01", 9.32],
  ["2017","00","01", 6.88]
];


let max = Math.max(...arr.map((o) => { return Number(o[3]) })); //9.99

let min = Math.min(...arr.map((o) => { return Number(o[3]) })); //6.88

// this can be rewritten like so:
// Math.min(...arr.map((o) => Number(o[3])));
//
// https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp


  console.log(max);
  console.log(min);
```

So,
before:

```js
let min = Math.min(Number(...arr.map((o) => { return o[3] }))); //9.99
```

after

```js
let min = Math.min(...arr.map((o) => { return Number(o[3]) })); //6.88
```